# Trying to swap out content in an iframe from an array of url's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an iframe on the site using a button with onclick to load the switcher function. I need to iterate through the url's in my array when the button is clicked.

Code is as follows:

```
var my_array = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4'];

function(){
    document.getElementById("#iframe").src="my_array";
}
```

I'm trying to iterate through the 4 urls as the button is clicked simultaneously, then reset to the first.

Answer (score 0):

Below is sample code to achieve this. I have shown a example with changing `div` 
 content, You can replace with `iframe` src

```js
var my_array = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4'];
var currIndex = 0;

$('button').on('click', function() {

  //$('#iframe').attr('src',my_array[currIndex]);
  $('div').html("src is : " + my_array[currIndex]); //demo purpose

  if (currIndex == my_array.length - 1) {
    currIndex = 0;
  } else {
    currIndex++;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

</div>

<button>next</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. This works flawlessly! Very much appreciated!

Comment: @Armyfrog84 I am glad to help. Also if this helped you resolve your issue you can mark it as answer as it helps the future crowd.

Answer (score 0):

```
var urls = [
  'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page',
  'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript',
  'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecma_International'
];

var prevIndex = urls.length;

function nextURL() {
  if (prevIndex >= urls.length - 1) {
    prevIndex = -1;
  }
  prevIndex += 1;
  document.getElementById('iframe').src = urls[prevIndex];
}

document
  .getElementById('next-url-btn')
  .addEventListener('click', nextURL);
```

Try it in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zrf8w0xu/).